# TinyMCE imagemanager not authenticating using DrupalAuthenticator for new admin users - drupal 7

Tags: authentication, drupal-7, tinymce, mcimagemanager

I've implemented TinyMCE imagemanager and filemanager with the wysiwyg module into Drupal 7 authenticating with DrupalAuthenticator. All works perfectly with the default Drupal admin login. I can access the file system to upload images etc.

A new user with admin permissions does not authenticate though and I can't see where to add permissons. Editor works fine but imagemanager defaults to login_session_auth.php.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by the excellent support at TinyMCE Forum:

http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=98488#p98488